# iOS Dynamic cell content

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uitableview

I have searched for this a lot and haven't found what I am looking for.

I want to have `UITableViewCell` such that each have dynamic content. For example, one cell can have a place name, address, phone number, image, etc. Another cell can have some or all of these attributes.

[image]

I know that I should have functions `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` return stuff appropriately.

The problem I am facing is that I have my cells designed in nib files, and am loading the layout from there. I can calculate the heights for each cell based on conditions(though this is tedious), also I need to arrange stuff in that cell if one thing is missing. For example, if place name is missing then move all the elements up via `setFrame:`.

There should be an easy way out I believe?

Comment: To be clear **you are using Storyboard**, right?  Then it's no problem, you just have more than one cell, for the table.

Comment: Hi Joe, yes, that's a way to go. However the combinations are really many and would lead me to design about 10 cell layouts. Wouldn't there be something that I can just pop off the unwanted elements and the cell readjusts the layout automatically.

Comment: 10 cell layouts for one table is normal? I just thought there would be a better way.

Comment: "10 cell layouts for one table is normal?" As I just said. Imagine, say, it's Amazon and the cells show product results.  Because of the wildly varying types of products (some have an image, some not, etc) there could be many, many possible cells.

Comment: By all means, could "auto layout" help you?  I don't know.

Comment: Hi Joe: I have now added link to image. That is how my cell would look like. Only the first element is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

In such dynamic cases I would not bother with using storyboards to accomplish this. It should be very easy to do this programatically...

If you really do need to create this in a storyboard you could generate a full cell which could consist of (for instance) 5 labels. Now in the table view data source I presume you have some array of objects where each element represents a single row in the table view. If so then in your case each of this object can have a method that will return an array of non-empty strings (the strings that will actually be displayed) which can be a dynamical count from 1 up to 5 strings.

If you do this you will request this array in method requesting the height for row at index path and by using this count you can then return the height of the row (for instance `numOfStrings*40.0f`). Inside the method requesting your cell you can simply fill those labels with the same array you use to calculate the height.

As for non storyboard approach I suggest you to override an `UITableViewCell`, generate a static method that will return you the cell height for string count and generate an initializer with the string array which should then iterate through the array generating the labels and setting the text to it.

Comment: Ok, yes this is the approach I thought about initially. Setting empty strings to label could leave those places blank. Possible workaround is setting the heights of empty labels to zero. But even with this approach, the other elements need to be moved up (or rearranged) - for a complex cell this may be a problem. I am looking for a more elegant approach where perhaps the other elements can be moved up automatically, that would help a lot.

Comment: In both approaches I described the labels would be "moved up" automatically. If you put static cells from the storyboard you then need to fill the correct ones: If you have only 1st and 4th string then you would fill 1st and 2nd label, NOT 1st and 4th.

Comment: Ok, I understand your storyboard approach better when I read again. It would work if everything was a UILabel, however everything is not a UILabel in my layout. There are buttons as well, for example the 4th item in the diagram i.e. call button.

Comment: Then how about making this whole row a section and every element in it is a row?